# How to fit in an image inside span tag?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image inside a span tag. But the problem is the image doesn't fit inside the span tag. Instead a part of the image goes out of the span tag.

[image]

[image]

```
    <span style="padding-right:3px; padding-top: 3px;">

    <img class="manImg" src="images/ico_mandatory.gif"></img>

    </span>
```

I want to have that bar inside the span i.e It should be adjacent to the text box.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: Don't use a span then? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Added the HTML code. Please have a look.

Comment: Experiment with `vertical-align` values.

Comment: maybe you must resize the image height

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this.

```
<span style="padding-right:3px; padding-top: 3px; display:inline-block;">

<img class="manImg" src="images/ico_mandatory.gif"></img>

</span>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` was the key for me

Answer (score 4):

Try using a div tag and block for span!

```
<div>
  <span style="padding-right:3px; padding-top: 3px; display:block;">
    <img class="manImg" src="images/ico_mandatory.gif"></img>
  </span>
</div>
```